# Render content type via Form Block module using module_invoke

Tags: forms, blocks

I am attempting to use the Form Block module so that I can place one of my content type forms in a block.  I seem to be able to get to the block but I'm not sure how to render it.  If I do a `print_r($block)` I see the block contents but I don't see anything to do with rendering it.

```
$block = module_invoke('formblock', 'block_view', 'csc_newsletter_subscription');

// Normally I would do something like this if it was just a block_view
$variables['newsletter_subscription_form'] = render($block['content']['#markup']);
```

And then I would be able to take the $newsletter_subscription_form variable and display it in my tpl file, but this does not seem to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can print a Block which is generated by a module like this.

```
$block = module_invoke(<module name>, 'block', 'view', <block id>);
print $block['content'];
```

User created block

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', <block id>);
```

example:

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 20);
print $block['content'];
```

In Your cas, since the forms are in blocks you can simply manage them via *exmple.com/admin/structure/block* path :)

Comment: I think that is basically what I have described in my post if I'm not mistaken.  Your syntax for D6 and mine for D7 right?  If I do the following:             `$block = module_invoke('formblock', 'block_view', 'csc_newsletter_subscription'); print_r($block); `     I get an huge array returned but there is no ['content'] item so trying to do `print $block['content'];`  doesn't return me anything.

Comment: Ok I think I got it:  `print render($block['content']);` I was missing the render call.  Thanks.